# ansible config file not found; using defaults

Tags: ansible

I have created venv called `ansible` and installed ansible using
`pip3 install ansible`. Now while checking ansible version `config file = None`

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.12
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ansible/ansible/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ansible/ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.4 (default, Aug 18 2019, 12:04:45) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

When I run ansible command it says `No config file found; using defaults` but which is that defaults file and where it can be found ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: ***"Which is that default file and where can it be found?"***

A: Short answer: There doesn't have to be any configuration file. In this case, the hardcoded defaults will apply.

Details:

- Quoting from [Getting the latest configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#getting-the-latest-configuration)

> *"If installing Ansible from a package manager, the latest ansible.cfg file should be present in /etc/ansible ..."*

- See [The configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file). Ansible searches configuration files in this order:

1. ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
2. ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
3. /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

- If there isn't any configuration file the defaults will apply. See the hardcoded defaults in [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings). The output of the below command will show you where each configuration option comes from

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump
```

Answer (score 5):

Run:

```
sudo apt remove ansible
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt install ansible
```

Now you can get the Ansible configuration location.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This actually worked for me. Since I used PIP to install Ansible, the config wasn't created automatically. These commands uninstall and reinstall via apt, which creates the config automatically.

Answer (score 1):

ansible configuration file is only created automatically during the installation if you perform the installation with package managers like yum or apt-get. If you installed ansible using pip you should create the configuration file manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- It's not wise to name your virtual environment `ansible` I suggest to rename it.
- Please share the command which you used to create the virtual environment (because you should activate it, I do not see it from what you have shared)
- If you want a quick fix for your issue , you could declare a environment variable named  `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` with the location of your desired configuration.

Ansible looks for the config file in this order:

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG (env var)
ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```